# Spacing Around Ampersands in tabular

Tags: tables, code

Does inserting   around `&` in `tabular` logically change the outcome?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
0&0\\0&0                %NON-SPACED VERSION
%0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0         %SPACED VERSION
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I'm currently using the unreadable non-spaced version because don't know if these spaces, though more readable, distort the outcome or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabular` and similar environments go to some lengths to make white space at the start and end of a cell ignored, specifically `\ignorespaces` is applied at the start and a single `\unskip` is applied at the end. So the first makes space tokens at the start of the cell not produce space, and the unskip removes glue from a space (or even an unguarded `\hspace`)  at the end.

Of course as always with TeX syntax it is context sensitive and a document could change this (for example in the scope of `\obeyspaces` but that seems unlikely here)